# Cannot start a JTA transaction from the IO thread

Tags: transactions, quarkus, mutiny

I'm trying to test some reactive code implemented with mutiny on quarkus 2.2.
This code do some sql query and I want a transactional method.

From my knowledge , for testing reactive code I have to await explicitly the result.
But when there is transaction I got a io.quarkus.runtime.BlockingOperationNotAllowedException: Cannot start a JTA transaction from the IO thread.

here the test :

```
  void myTest() throws InterruptedException, SystemException, NotSupportedException {
    final Prestation prestation = Prestation.builder().build();
    final Uni<Uni<Integer>> uniUni = Uni.createFrom().voidItem().onItem().transformToUni(unused -> prestationCreate.upsert(prestation)).onItem()
            .transformToUni(aBoolean -> {
                return prestationClosedThePreviousDaySelect.select2Multi(LocalDate.of(2021, 04, 29))
                        .collect().asList();
            })
            .onItem()
            .transformToUni(prestations -> Uni.createFrom().item(prestationRepository.deleteAll()))
            .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor());

    final UniAssertSubscriber<Uni<Integer>> uniUniAssertSubscriber = uniUni.subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create());
    uniUniAssertSubscriber.awaitItem()
            .assertCompleted();
}
```

With this code the exception will be thrown at the last line.

If I replace the last line with listUniAssertSubscriber.assertCompleted();, tests fails with "Expected a completion event, but didn't received it."

Anybody know if there is a way to test reactive code with transaction ?

Comment: How are you starting your transaction?, I cannot see it on the example, which are your dependencies regarding database access and transaction?, are you using panache?

Comment: Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong: prestationClosedThePreviousDaySelect.select2Multi is producing its result on an I/O thread (you can add .log() to check), and deleteAll is transactional? In that case, it's not a runSubscriptionOn that you need, but an emitOn(...) just before the onItem().

Comment: Thank you @Clement, when a use emitOn instead runSubsritionOn there is no more exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(copying my comment, confirmed by the reporter)

`prestationClosedThePreviousDaySelect.select2Multi` produces its result on an I/O thread (you can add .log() to check), and `deleteAll` is transactional?.
In that case, it's not a `runSubscriptionOn` that you need, but an `emitOn(...)` just before the `onItem()`